# Having a problem with visual studio Databinding when leaving and coming back to the same form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

For making this simply I have two forms a button on each to navigate between the two forms. Then on one I have a checkbox and label when the checkbox is checked it displays the label by using the following code in the form.load event:

```
Me.label1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", Me.checkbox1, "Checked")
```

The problem is if I were to leave the form with the checkbox and label and the checkbox is not checked and then I come back to the form with the checkbox and try and check it the label doesn't show up any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: You need to store the information somewhere.  Settings, File, Database, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Delete that line of code from the form load
- Open your form in the designer, the one with the label and the checkbox on it
- Click the checkbox
- In the Properties grid expand (PropertyBinding) and open the drop down next to (none), click New at the bottom

[image]

- Pick an initial value, and choose a name for the setting. Make it user scoped if you want to be able to save it and restore it next time the program opens

[image]

- Now go to your label, properties, click the [...] next to (PropertyBinding) to see a list of all bindable properties, scroll to Visible and drop down to choose the same setting

[image]

- Run the program.

---

Side note; when I did this I think I may have encountered a bug/feature of databinding (that I plan to research more) in that the behavior was only as expected if the bool starts out as true (so the control is visible) when the binding is set up. If the control is invisible, it never binds properly to see when the property has become true - so as a workaround (purely in this case where we're binding Visible), replace he call to InitializeComponent() with this, in the form's constructor:

```
        if (!Properties.Settings.Default.FormatWithoutConfirmation)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.FormatWithoutConfirmation = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            Properties.Settings.Default.FormatWithoutConfirmation = false;
        }
        else
            InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work it behaved the same way as the load event. I even tried adding in the if statements in the constructor and that didn't help any either.

Comment: Make the label visible all the time, and bind to the Boolean property enabled instead.. does it work as you expect(obv not in terms of visibility, but is it enabled when checked and disabled when not checked)? If so I think it's related to that oddity I mention in the final para; a control that is invisible when it's databinding for visibility is set will not listen to any value hangs to make it visible, but the idea of making it visible (if invisible) before binding it (in init component) then making invisible again seems to work for me. To be clear, that code I gave was the whole constructor